# django connecting to mysql in docker gets "wrong" IP address

Tags: mysql, django, docker, authentication

I am attempting to connect to a remote mysql db from my dockerized django app. This works as expected:

```
In [2]: pymysql.connect(host='remote-host.com', user='user', password='bogus')
Out[2]: OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'172.XX.XX.XX' (using password: YES)")
In [3]: pymysql.connect(host='remote-host.com', user='user', password='secret')
Out[3]: <pymysql.connections.Connection at 0x401ef682b0>
```

But this does not (from within django runserver):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'192.168.80.4' (using password: YES)")
```

So somehow the shell-based connection is picking up a 172/ IP address for the client (presumably the docker bridge IP - it doesn't correspond to my laptop's en0 IP at any rate), where the exact same code, exact same connection params within runserver causes the mysql server to see the IP of the docker container.

Anyone know what's going on, and more importantly how I can prevent it?

Attempted:

Well, not really much I can do since I don't have access to modify mysql's accepted host list or how it determines the client IP.

Expected:

The same IP address to be used in both connections.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the db host was being modified by some middleware and so wasn't actually hitting the remote host. That said, I'd still like to know why the different source IPs were getting set.